# not able to select a column outside left join

Tags: sql

I am working with the below query

```
SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT DISTINCT 
                 a.Number
                ,a.Description
                ,ISNULL(temp.Quantity,0) Quantity
                ,LastReceived
                ,LastIssued
                FROM Article a
                LEFT JOIN (
                        select  ss.ArticleId
                                , ss.Quantity 
                                , max(lastreceiveddate) as LastReceived
                                , max(lastissueddate) as LastIssued
                        from StockSummary ss
                        where ss.UnitId = 8
                        group by ss.ArticleId, ss.StockQuantity
                        having (MAX(ss.LastReceivedDate) < '2014-09-01' or MAX(ss.LastReceivedDate) is NULL)
                                AND (MAX(ss.LastIssuedDate) < '2014-09-01' or MAX(ss.LastIssuedDate) is NULL)
                        ) temp on a.Id = temp.ArticleId
        WHERE a.UnitId = 8 
        ) main
ORDER BY main.Number
```

What i want to achieve is to select the articles only with the MAX(ss.LastReceivedDate) and MAX(ss.LastIssuedDate) condition in the Left join query and then do the Quantity Select in the main query.
Note: the quantity column can be 0 or NULL.
Kindly help

Comment: Is your column called 'StockQuantity' or 'Quantity'? Are you sure all the columns you are using in your query exist in the respective tables with same name?

Comment: What problem are you having with this? Can you show some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Sorry, The column name is quantity. Not stock quantity

Comment: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Apologies for late reply. But i figured out the solution, i did a inner join again after the left join on Stock summary table and to get Quantity.